# single app REST API client front-end for Node.Js framework?

Tags: node.js, frameworks, admin, panel

I have to create an admin panel that will rely on an API I created.
I would like to use an framework that will speed up my dev. (create request based on field provided by user, search ,etc)
To make it , I want to make a single app REST API client front-end. I didn't find a framework that could do that easily (for example : one that use a rest api client and a another front-end app)

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I discover and that could help another guys :

https://github.com/marmelab/restful.js

With some explanation : https://marmelab.com/blog/2015/03/10/deal-easily-with-your-rest-api-using-restful-js.html

Answer (score 0):

No one will choose that for you. Go to this website:

- http://nodeframework.com/

And read about all of the framkeworks there. Compare their differences and see which is the best tool for the job for you. Every one of them has its use, every one of them is good for something, every one of them has its strengths and its weaknesses. For API development most of the people choose Express, Hapi, Restify or LoopBack but there are much more than just those few to choose from. You need to test for yourself which works for you.

Comment: Thanks your answer but if I could suggest something to you : take time to think by yourself (instead of use a well-known phrase). I know how to google it : What I wanted is an single app REST API client front-end framework for nodejs , not just a HTTP framework